# Menu link opens with #.U3htHECyIpJ tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a problem while opening the menu links .It opens with id links such as http://websamplenow.com/30/educare/publishing.php#.U3iEhECyIpI  instead I want it to open http://websamplenow.com/30/educare/publishing.php

Iam currently working on bootstrap format

THanks

Comment: you're gonna have to include your codes inside this question so that it can be diagnosed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<a class="addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=300&amp;pubid=ra-53215daa261d5768"><img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif" width="125" height="16" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0"/></a>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53215daa261d5768"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

This jquery was creating link with id .It solved :)